# Remove empy space at compile time

Tags: c++, char, metaprogramming

I kept wondering if it's possible to remove the blank spaces in the next paragraph at compile time.

```
int main()
{
    const char* paragraph = "This is an example";
    //expect Thisisanexample
}
```

I was thinking maybe with meta programming ??

Comment: Yes, [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) is even `constexpr` in C++20.

Comment: Maybe an example with a recursive function? With lower  C++ standard??

Answer (score 2):

You might have something like:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<char, N> without_space(const char (&s)[N])
{
    std::array<char, N> res{};
    std::size_t i = 0;

    for (auto c : s) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            res[i++] = c;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

C++17 currently, as `std::array` misses some `constexpr` before :-/

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9634097bb74dc0b6)

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to not return the extra `\0`s at the end.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: gcc/clang have udl extension to have literal string as char sequence in template. That would allow to return correct size. With regular argument, I don't see other way.